# In C# what is the correct RegEx to get get words between two words, but exclude the boundaries?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Given the following string:

> Loaded data from: schema.table from database with runtime 23s.

I'd like to extract `schema.table` from the string. The current re

I'm currently using this pattern: `:(\s+)(.+)(\s+)from` with help from this comment:
[Capturing text between two words using a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575075/capturing-text-between-two-words-using-a-regular-expression#comment15314205_11575164)

I'd like to know how I can modify this RegEx to exclude the `:` and `from` the match.

Comment: you could just save it in a variable and cut : and from away

Comment: What's the big deal excluding `:` and `from` from the match ? You've already heavily captured what you want. Also, the answer you've chosen _also_ uses a capture buffer while trmming everything else. What's that all about? And, you don't say `schema.table` in your regex, you say from here `:\s+ALL THE WAY FROM ON DOWN TO FROM to\s+from` way too many form's there, but you don't say if that's ok.

Comment: @sln thanks for the feedback. the data is consistently in the form of the search pattern but `schema.table` was just a generic way of identifying the data that i needed, but it's not ever`schema.table`. sometimes it's `dbo.word`, or `w.test`, etc.

Comment: @sln fair enough - unfortunately most people aren't great at Regex (myself included) so when we see something that works then we're quite pleased.

Comment: @sln so show me a better way

Comment: @sln ok. did i address your original question sufficiently, or do you need more?

Answer (score 2):

You can use lookarounds:

```
(?<=:\s+)(.+?)(?=\s+from)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://fiddle.re/dq1fr6)

Answer (score 2):

Use match but don't capture `(?: )` which provides an anchor (the `:` and `\s`) *for* the match to work, but it is not captured as a final output.

Then one can simply get the following text out of the group capture which I have named `Text` to easily extract it:

```
string text = "Loaded data from: schema.table from database with runtime 23s.";
string pattern = @"(?::\s)(?<Text>[^\s]+)";

// Outputs "schema.table"
Console.WriteLine (Regex.Match(text, pattern).Groups["Text"].Value);
```

Otherwise without the naming capture, it would be index 1 off of the group.